# Country / City / State / Business database structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-design

I'm working on a rails app (if that's relevant) and I'm needing to have users create a list of event at businesses all over the world and I'm wondering what the best way to structure it would be. I would like for the user to select a country, then a state inside of that, and then a city, and then a business where each selection scopes the options for the next. If a business doesn't exist in the database, I want to allow the user to type in their option and then that will be a possible selection for the next user who goes through this process. What's the best way to approach this?

I'm assuming I need to model this as country has many states has many cities has many businesses.. please let me know if this is the correct structure for this.

Also, are there common databases of countries/states/cities that I should use? Are there services that I should use? Is there a benefit to one over the other, or is there a completely different, better approach? I know this is nothing new, but I'm not sure of the best way to approach this, so I'm looking for some direction..

Let me know what you all have learned from experience.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm from China and there is no such things called `states` in China, only `provinces` but with some exceptions some `cities` are directly adjacent to the country. Some small countries like Singapore don't have states or provinces at all. Their top level administrative regions are districts.

Comment: Yes from experience it is difficult to normalize location. Might be easier to just store latlng in the dB and use Google maps to get a location name which includes city/state/provinces/jungle/whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use postal codes for general navigation. Services like Google Maps can provide the rest (state, country or whatever).

Just my two cents...

Answer (score 1):

Given that all of this varies greatly depending on country (including the actual address format), I would opt for an approach like this:

1. Let the user pick a business/latlong pair.
2. Try to reverse geocode said business or location.
3. Allow the user to make corrections to the geocoded info.

Don't try to impose a schema on something that is basically impossible to standardize. Instead let the users — with as much assistance as possible — take care of the hard part, they have the knowledge about their country that you lack.